# How to subset and apply a function across the dataset

Tags: r

I have a list of prices for different items in the same dataset.

```
abc1 <- c("2005-09-18", "ABC", 99.00)
abc2 <- c("2005-09-19", "ABC", 98.00)
abc3 <- c("2005-09-20", "ABC", 98.50)
abc4 <- c("2005-09-21", "ABC", 97.75)
def1 <- c("2005-09-14", "DEF", 79.00)
def2 <- c("2005-09-15", "DEF", 78.00)
def3 <- c("2005-09-16", "DEF", 78.50)
def4 <- c("2005-09-20", "DEF", 77.75)

df <- data.frame(rbind(abc1, abc2, abc3, abc4, def1, def2, def3, def4))
```

the above quick table would result in :

```
             X1  X2    X3
abc1 2005-09-18 ABC    99
abc2 2005-09-19 ABC    98
abc3 2005-09-20 ABC  98.5
abc4 2005-09-21 ABC 97.75
def1 2005-09-14 DEF    79
def2 2005-09-15 DEF    78
def3 2005-09-16 DEF  78.5
def4 2005-09-20 DEF 77.75
```

I would like to add a column, say X4, which would be the variation of today, versus the previous day, for a specific X2.  So x4 would have the following value:

```
 X4
 0,0%
-1,0%
 0,5%
-0,8%
 0,0%
-1,3%
 0,6%
-1,0%
```

The goal would be to do  that for all the different items in X3. Ideally without splitting the table. I think the date is always going to be in the right order, but just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can group by 'X2' and take the difference of adjacent elements with `diff`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(X2) %>%
   mutate(X4 = c(0, diff(X3)))
```

Or after grouping by 'X2', take the difference between the 'X2' and the `lag` of 'X2'

```
df %>%
   group_by(X2) %>%
   mutate(X4 = X3 - lag(X3, default = first(X3)))
```

Comment: `df %>%
  group_by(X2) %>%
  mutate(X4 = (X3 - lag(X3, default = first(X3)))/lag(X3, default = first(X3)))`  is the one i piked up, Thank you @Akrun

Comment: Actually I get this error `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘group_by’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’`

Comment: @Etienne  Have you loaded `dplyr`.  dplyr should work for `data.frame`.  Can you try on a fresh session with only `dplyr` loaded.  Also, please check the `str(yourdata)` for any unusual attributes.  If that is the case, try with `as.data.frame(yourdata)` and then apply

Comment: I am loading as: `library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(quantmod)
library(SparkR)
library(knitr)
library(dplyr)`

Comment: @Etienne  Are you running on `Spark`.  Please check if some of the tidyverse functions are compatible with that

Comment: Ok The above order works better.  Basically order matters.

Comment: @Etienne  sorryl didn't get your comments

Comment: @Etienne Please check the `str(yourdata)` and see how it is different from a normal dataset `str(mtcars)`.  To rule out any other env issues, you can run a group by on `mtcars`, check if it runs fine, then it would be the structure attributes of your data that is causing the problem

Comment: Sorry, I was loading this way initially and I had the compatibility error.: 
`library(knitr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(quantmod)
library(SparkR)` Then changed to `library(lubridate) library(tidyr) library(quantmod) library(SparkR) library(knitr) library(dplyr)` and now it is ok.

Comment: @Etienne  okay, so now you have the issue with `group_by`, right?  I would check on a normal data (see my previous comment)

Answer (score 2):

Just a little hint: You wanted to calculate the difference in percent, not the absolute difference.

You have to adjust the formula to do so, otherwise your results are wrong :-).

```
df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(X2) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(X4 = (X3/lag(X3, default = first(X3)) - 1) * 100)

  X1         X2       X3     X4
  <fct>      <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2005-09-18 ABC    99    0    
2 2005-09-19 ABC    98   -1.01 
3 2005-09-20 ABC    98.5  0.510
4 2005-09-21 ABC    97.8 -0.761
5 2005-09-14 DEF    79    0    
6 2005-09-15 DEF    78   -1.27 
7 2005-09-16 DEF    78.5  0.641
8 2005-09-20 DEF    77.8 -0.955
```

Comment: Actually I get this error `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘group_by’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’`